# Running Ubuntu on Nextbook NXW8QC16

Tags: touchscreen, tablet, system-requirements

I have a Nextbook NXW8QC serial no starting with YFG. After a win update, the tablet restarted. On restart it stuck in a boot loop error. Two days of calls to microsoft without a solution convinced me to try using a better os. Can I run Ubuntu on this tablet? If yes, what equip would i need?  tablet has no keyboard, or other input device. Touch screen only.

Any help getting the tablet running again would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Almost forgot. OEM OS is win 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Possibly using a OTG usb adapter connecting a usb keyboard and a bootable usb flash drive you may be able to reinstall by tapping ESC key when first booting up. you will be able to see the bios settings that way, but the options are limited.

Tampered with the settings a little, but dont want to try myself and screw it up.